# Convert MongoDB Collection ObjectId to _id "string"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

Is it possible to batch update a mongo collection which has `_id :ObjectId("22332"`) inside of a _id field into a string so `_id : "22332"` is used instead

I am using Meteor and I have imported csv with mongoimport but it automatically adds the ObjectId as ("22332") I dont want to break the default meteor `_id` functionality and have to put `._str` on every javascript file.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5696cf153f8d6d60f723268b"),
    "NTitle" : 18,
    "field1" : "company announces Private Placement",
    "field2" : "111099432820040602PP.pdf",
    "field3" : "Vancouver, BC, June 2, 2004...... ",
    "field4" : "2004-02-06",
    "field5" : "YES"
}
```

I would like this instead

```
{
    "_id" : 5696cf153f8d6d60f723268b,
    "NTitle" : 18,
    "field1" : "company announces Private Placement",
    "field2" : "111099432820040602PP.pdf",
    "field3" : "Vancouver, BC, June 2, 2004...... ",
    "field4" : "2004-02-06",
    "field5" : "YES"
}
```

This is a insert script.

```
Meteor.methods({
  postInsert: function(postAttributes) {
    check(Meteor.userId(), String);
    check(postAttributes, {
      title: String,
      postContent: String,
      timeToEnable: Date,
      timeDisplay:String,
      year: Number,
      month: Number,
      day: Number,
      hours: Number,
      timeString : String,
      postNow: Date

    });
    var user = Meteor.user();
    var post = _.extend(postAttributes, {
      userId: user._id,
      author: user.username,
      submitted: new Date()
    });
    var postId = Posts.insert(post);
    return {
      _id: postId
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Because it involves parsing a string, it might not be possible to do it purely with mongoDB. However, you can write a small script that just grabs records, parses the id, and then updates it. Wouldn't be very hard to write it.

Comment: @khuderm would I be writing in javascript in the server side of meteor? And do you have a resource or example I could start with.

Comment: im assuming you already have code to select/insert/update/delete from your mongo database. I am not very familiar with meteor so i wouldn't know. What language are you using for your server side code?

Comment: I have added the insert script above. I am using javascript on server and client.

Comment: select a set from the db in an infinite loop. if there are no results, exit. If there are, parse the id string with js substr or the meteor equivalent. update the same record with the new id. select next set from db and the process starts over in the loop.

Comment: It might be just me, but why exactly do you want that? An ObjectId contains some information, since it is a representation of a machine Id and a timestamp, whereas the string-only representation would have to be reparsed to extract that info. If you don't want to use an ObjectId, simply write a UUID.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg The default id generation technique is 'STRING'. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection Since I already have written my code for that setup and it is the default Meteor setup I would rather change this collection than everything else I have already built.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I did not choose arbitrarily. I did get it working with ObjectId. I do understand that I am losing a embedded timestamp and interoperability with other applications. The reason to use a randomized string is to enables latency compensation in Meteor so you can create the ID on the client and render the UI before talking to the server. Now I don't even think my app needs it at the moment, but I want that option as it grows. The ability to change between the two id types is more valuable to me. I have learned the benefit of both options now. Its situational not right or wrong

Comment: Creating an UI on the client is a perfect intrusion vector. Unless you have a  granular permission model down to the object level, attaching values to an id which the client can arbitrarily send leads to easy possibility of data destruction. You should be able to build the UI and request the data on load, if I am not mistaken. As a comment between peers: I have a strong feeling the [root of all evil strikes again](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a rough example of what solved my problem.**

*export csv from phpmyadmin*

*install mongodb locally*

run

```
mongoimport -h localhost:3001 --db meteor --collection news4 --type csv --file env_news.csv --fields NID,NTitle,NPDF,NDesc,NAdded,NActive
```

**server/changeData.js**

```
var test = News4.find().fetch();
var test1 = News4Final.find().fetch();

for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++){

News4Final.insert({_id : test[i]._id._str}); //Run this Firsttime.

//Run everything below  after first run

//var submitted = new Date(test[i].NAdded);

/*News4Final.update(test1[i]._id, {$set: {
title: test[i].NTitle,
PDF : test[i].NPDF,
postContent : test[i].NDesc,
submitted : submitted

}},{multi: false});*/


}
```

Dumb local Databse

```
mongodump --port 3001
```

senddatabase upto compose.io mongodb server.

```
mongorestore --host caneww.60.mon342.com:10654 --db enwave -u admin -p password dump/meteor
```

**use meteor up and set up databse invironment variables. Also turn off mongodb setup to false in mup.json**

```
"MONGO_URL": "mongodb://admin:password@cand4ate.40.mongolayer.com:10644,candidate.12.mongolayer.com:11274/enwdve?replicaSet=set-569886d8c55a7400102b",
"MONGO_OPLOG_URL": "mongodb://admin:password@candi4te.40.mongolayer.com:10254,candidate.12.mongolayer.com:1d274/local?authSource=enwddve"
```